# How do I use a sub query in the SELECT part with DBIx::Class?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, subquery, dbix-class

Please help to write this MySQL query in `DBIx::Class` (to have an example on how to use subqueries in `DBIx::Class`):

```
SELECT x, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.y=x) AS c FROM t1 WHERE t1.z=123
```

(I know that it can be rewritten as `JOIN` with `GROUP BY`, but I want namely subquery (for an example to get my hands on).)

`DBIx::Class` docs give extensive review of using subqueries in `WHERE` clause but I didn't find how to use a subquery in the `SELECT` fields list (as in the above example).

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: @DaveCross The problem is that I don't know the syntax for it.

Comment: Thanks @porton, I was searching for the `get_columns` syntax all day long yesterday and for some reason found it only today thanks to your question. Asking for self helps others ✊

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track. The [`as_query`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#as_query) is what you need. But you also need the [`columns` option](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#columns) in the second hashref. Make sure you use [`count_rs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#count_rs) on the sub query, which flips the internal switch to produce a resultset with `COUNT(*)` in it.

```
my $obj = ResultSet('TableOne')->search(
    { 
         z => 123,
    },
    {
        columns => [
            'x',
            {
                c => ResultSet('TableTwo')->search(
                    {
                        'y' => {
                            -ident => 'me.x',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        alias => 'sub_query', # this name is arbitrary
                    },
                )->count_rs->as_query,
            },
        ],
    }
)->first;
```

The resulting query will look something like this:

```
SELECT me.x, ( 
    SELECT COUNT( * ) 
      FROM table_two sub_query
    WHERE y = me.x
   )
  FROM table_one me
WHERE me.z = 123
```

As you can see, the value that we selected via the sub query is not called `c` in the SQL, but it is called `c` in the object's data.

```
use DDP;
p $obj;

DB::Result::TableOne  {
    # ...
    internals: {
        _column_data     {
            x        "foo",
            c        "bar"
        },
        _in_storage      1,
        _result_source   DBIx::Class::ResultSource::Table
    }
}
```

You can access it with [`get_column`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Row#get_column) on the row object.

```
say $obj->get_column('c');
# bar
```

Comment: hi. May you please extend your example to use `EXISTS` keyword, e.g. `SELECT exists( select .... ) `

Comment: @EugenKonkov you mean the DBIC code? Interesting. I guess that'll just be `c => { '-exists' => ResultSet('foo')->count_rs->as_query }`.

Comment: I have found. I should use [`+select` and `+as`](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=882510) to name the column which value is select statement. Otherwise there will be error. https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=126958

Comment: @EugenKonkov I agree that your ticket makes sense, but I don't see how it's relevant to your previous comment regarding the `EXISTS` keyword.

Comment: I was looking for solution to make subquery with exists keyword. Problem was with that your guess did not work without `+as` attribute (when prefetch is also required) Thus I have ask about an example.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I see. I didn't know about the `EXISTS` keyword at all. Just had to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `prefetch` and you want select subquery result you must name your subqueries, otherwise you will get the error (see comments under simbabque's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51188816/4632019))

```
my $partial =  $c->model( 'ServicePackageSet' )->search([
    { service_type_id_covered => { -ident => 'me.id' } },
    { service_type_id_surplus => { -ident => 'me.id' } },
],{ select => \1 });

my $pricelist =  $c->model( 'ServiceTree' )->search({
},{
    '+select' => { exists => $partial->as_query },
    '+as' => [ 'partial' ],
    prefetch => [qw/ Price Package /],
    order_by => [qw/ Package.short_name name /],
});
```

though if you want to use subquery as filter it will work without naming:

```
my $pricelist =  $c->model( 'ServiceTree' )->search({
    -not_exists => $partial->as_query
},{
    prefetch => [qw/ Price Package /],
    order_by => [qw/ Package.short_name name /],
});
```